# Value of optional type 'Any?' not unwrapped

Tags: swift, facebook-login, option-type, any

I'm trying to implement facebook login. Learning from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNfrBdyEvmY but there is an error of type above. Here is my code:

```
let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start { (connection, result, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error ?? "error")
            return
        }
        if let email = result["email"] as? String{
            print("Email: \(email)")
        }
    }
```

[image]
Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: i did but it gives another error "type any has no subscript members"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast type Any to Swift dictionary type, you can do it in this way:

```
if let userInfo = result as? [String: Any] {
    let email = userInfo["email"] as? String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those types of errors actually give you an option to use Xcode autocorrect feature. If you click the red circle and then click the fix it shows, it should automatically fix your issue. It's not always accurate but 90% of the time, it is.